# My touchpad is not working I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop what should I do?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-132-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-135-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-135-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-135-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-135-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-135-generic (--configure):No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-135-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-135-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-135-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-135-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-132-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-135-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
 linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-wily
 linux-generic-lts-wily
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-132-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-135-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
 linux-image-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in the console:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

This is for enabling the touchpad

Or this will unload and reload the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Comment: not working.....please give other suggestions ty

Comment: NOW is it working

Comment: no i tried this it is not working yet